# Why json parsing is not working?

Tags: android, json

I'm fetching data through `JSON-Parsing`, but getting "NullPointerException" and `Error A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of {`. following is what I have tried so far :

```
/** Method for returning JSONObject */
protected JSONObject lastTweet() {

    try {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode >= 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject lastT = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            return (lastT);
        } else {
            Log.e(MY_TAG, "Error");
            return null;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(MY_TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(MY_TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(MY_TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now when I actually make this code work for me is following :

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Please wait..");
            dialog.setMessage("Data is being loaded");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) { // TODO
            try {
                jsonObject = lastTweet();
                return jsonObject.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) { // TODO
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            textView.setText(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);
```

that gives me the following `LogCat` :

[image: Logcat snap shot]

How to solve that issue?

Comment: You get json object form server, not array. Try JSONObject o = new JSONObject (data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json you are retriewing is not a JSONArray, it is a JSONObject

Change this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
```

To this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (data);
JSONArray contactsJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacts");

// TODO: loop over contactsJsonArray
JSONObject contactJsonObject = contactsJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String nameOfAContact = contactJsonObject.getString("name");
```

Comment: thanks now if I write `return contactsJsonArray.getString(2)`, I get the whole array. how get specific name from that  array..?

Comment: I've demonstrated getting name attr of the first JsonObject in contactsJsonArray.

Answer (score 1):

The error contains the solution:

`A JSONArray text must start with '['`

Check if the response starts with a `[` rather than a `{`.
If it is true you are receiving a JSONObject, and not a JSONArray.

Comment: how can I `DEBUG` that...?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line "JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);" and check if the String data starts with a "[" or with a "}"

Answer (score 1):

you are storing json object in json array

use this:: 
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (data);

Answer (score 0):

JSON should start and end with { and }, are you sure your json is

```
{"contacts":[{},{}]}
```

and not only

```
"contacts":[{},{}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're casting a `JSONObject` as a `JSONArray`.
Change this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
```

to this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("contacts");
```